# Pass Data from initial requests to last request (Scrapy)

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new in scrapy . Can any one tell me ,how can I pass data from initial request to subsequent requests ? What is wrong in my code ?

class SizeCrawler(CrawlSpider):

```
name = "size-uk-crawl"
allowed_domians = ["size.co.uk"]
start_urls = ["http://www.size.co.uk"]

# Set the rules for scraping all the available products of a website
rules = (
    Rule(
        SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=(
            "(//*[@id='primaryNavigation']/li/span/a)[position() >= 3]",  # get all cloths, footwear and accessories
            "//*[@id='categoryMenu']//li/a")),                            # get all categories
        follow=True, process_request='add_gender'
    ),
    Rule(
        SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=(
            "//div[@class='product-list gallery-view medium-images']/ol//h2/a")),
        callback='parse_product'
    ),

)
def add_gender(self, request):

    # Select the value for gender here
    logging.info(request.meta)
    gender = request.meta.get('link_text')
    if gender == 'ForWomen':
        gender = 'women'
    else:
        gender = 'men'
    request.meta['gender'] = gender

    return request

def parse_product(self, response):

    # Problem here
    # I am not getting gender information here
    logging.info(response.meta)
    logging.info(response.request.meta)
```

Comment: In response.meta OR in response.request.meta , there is no ("gender") information

Comment: This is response.meta                                                                          INFO: {'download_timeout': 180.0, 'redirect_urls': ['http://size.co.uk/product/adidas-originals-three-pack-socks/043678/'], 'depth': 2, 'download_latency': 0.9475619792938232, 'download_slot': 'size.co.uk', 'redirect_times': 1, 'link_text': u'Three Pack Socks', 'rule': 1, 'redirect_ttl': 19}

Answer (score 0):

you have added callback=parse_product in one rule and process request in the other rule. are you sure this is what you want to do ? the request that is leading to parse_product will not be getting processed by add gender.